# SQL Multiple Selects and Group Bys

Tags: mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

Here is my data:

[image]

I want to find the number of unique SessionIds for each date that fulfills the following conditions:
when the number of "/topic" in one sessionid =1, the number of "/detail" in the same sessionid also equals 1. So for my case, sessionid=1 (412) is the only sessionid that meets the requirement.

Here is the code I used: (table name is we)

```
SELECT count( Distinct sessionid) 
from
    ( Select sessionid, count(search like "/topic%") as TN and Count(search like "/detail%") as DN from we GROUP BY date order by date) as my_table 
WHERE TN ==1 and DN=1
```

Sorry about the messy code, but it should print out [1,0] for date 412, and date 413. but its not working. any advice? Many thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE, 
       count(Distinct sessionid) 
FROM (Select sessionid, 
             DATE,
             SUM(CASE WHEN search like '/topic%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TN, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN search like '/detail%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DN 
    from we 
    GROUP BY sessionid, DATE
    ) as my_table 
WHERE TN = 1 AND DN = 1
GROUP BY DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with the subquery.  Your syntax is a bit off (use `sum()` rather than `count()`, for instance) and the `group by` keys are not correct.  But, you seem to be looking for:

```
select date, count(Distinct sessionid)
from (select date, sessionid,
             sum(search like "/topic%") as TN, sum(search like "/detail%") as DN
      from we
      group by date, sessionid
     ) t
whereTN = 1 and DN = 1
group by date;
```